# What is the initial function of a thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, language-lawyer

The C++20 draft, [[except.handle]/12](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/except#handle-12) says: (emphasis added)

> Exceptions thrown in destructors of objects with thread storage duration or in constructors of namespace-scope objects with thread storage duration are not caught by a function-try-block on **the initial function of the thread**.

and [[except.terminate]/1.10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/except#terminate-1.10) says (emphasis added)

> In some situations exception handling is abandoned for less subtle
> error handling techniques. [Note 1: These situations are:
>
> - [..]
> - (1.10) when execution of **the initial function of a thread** exits via an exception [..]

What is "the initial function of a thread"? Is it the `main` function? Is it the implementation of `std::invoke` as specified in [[thread.thread.constr]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/thread.thread.constr#6)? or something else?

I asked someone for that, and the answer was that the initial function of a thread is the first function runned by this thread; and the first function runned by a thread is always the implementation of `std::invoke`. Is this true?

If that's not true, what is the actual definition of the "initial function of a thread" in the context of the above standard wording?

Comment: The initial thread function is the function *you* provide to the constructor of std::thread.

Comment: I don't see it defined anywhere. But I don't think it is really relevant for the two cases you mention. The second one is a non-normative note and the first one only clarifies that something _doesn't_ happen which isn't specified to happen anywhere anyway. But in either case it looks to me that the intended meaning is the function which `std::invoke` in https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/thread#thread.constr-6 will invoke, although there may be constructors called before that.

Comment: When you create a `std::thread` object you pass in a function for the thread to execute. That's the initial function.

Comment: @PeteBecker This is also what I intuitively came to think.  However, the thread does not execute necessarily a function.  It can be any invocable object (e.g. a class with an opearator()). I think that the standard makers would not have made such an approximation.  The only function mentioned in [thread.thread.constr], is std::invoke(). I think it doesn't actually matter much in this problem statement:  invoke(f) would not catch more than f().

Comment: @Christophe -- a thread **always** executes a function. `operator()` **is** a function. Yes, I simplified it. If you want the full details: when you pass a callable object, it results in a function call in the new thread. That function is the "initial function".

Answer (score 5):

> I asked someone for that, and the answer was that the initial function of a thread is the first function runned by this thread; and the first function runned by a thread is always the implementation of `std::invoke`. Is this true?

This is not *meaningfully* true.

The phrase "initial function" has no particular definition in the standard, so it's meant to be taken literally: the function initially run by a `thread`. And the constructor of `std::thread/jthread` [does say that:](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/thread.thread.constr#6)

> The new thread of execution executes
>
> ```
> invoke(decay-copy(std::forward<F>(f)), decay-copy(std::forward<Args>(args))...)
> ```
>
> with the calls to decay-copy being evaluated in the constructing thread.

However, the "as if" rule still applies. A particular implementation does not specifically have to use `std::invoke`; it only must behave "as if" it did. And while users are allowed to provide specializations for standard library class templates with user-defined types, they are *not* allowed to specialize standard library *function* templates, or overload them outside of very specific circumstances. So there's no way for a user to (validly) interfere with the meaning of `std::invoke`.

As such, an implementation doesn't specifically have to use `std::invoke` at all. It could use behavior equivalent to it.

More importantly... it wouldn't matter.

Your program can't change what happens after the call to the function you give the `thread`. Since you cannot affect that code, any behavior around the "initial function" wording applies to the only thing you *can* control: the behavior of the function you give it

So if the function you give `thread` emits an exception, that will *necessarily* trigger the clause about the behavior of an "initial function of the thread" which doesn't catch an exception. There is no way to cause something below that function call to catch or otherwise interfere with such clauses.

So for all meaningful purposes, "initial function of the thread" is "whatever function you pass that gets called by `thread/jthread`'s constructor".

Comment: Very clear. +1.  Since it's a language lawyer question, I'd suggest to reword a "*function you pass that gets called by ...*" since one may not necessarily pass a function.  What about "*function that gets called by ... based on the arguments passed*" ?

Comment: There is another mention of "_initial function_" in the standard (https://eel.is/c++draft/basic#start.dynamic-7.sentence-1). That one I am not actually sure that the precise meaning doesn't matter. For example, if the implementation doesn't use deferred initialization, is it guaranteed that a thread-local variable is initialized before it is used in a constructor called from `std::invoke` for a function parameter of "_"whatever function you pass that gets called by thread/jthread's constructor"._" ? (E.g. is https://godbolt.org/z/9oGboxKe3 guaranteed to print `43`?)

Comment: @user17732522: I'm pretty sure "The completion of the invocation of the constructor synchronizes with the beginning of the invocation of the copy of `f`." takes care of it. The decay-copies are part of the constructor, so they "synchronize with" the call to `f`'s decay-copy.

Comment: @NicolBolas I don't mean the decay-copies. Inside `std::invoke`, which is already running purely in the new thread without synchronization, there must be another move construction from the rvalue reference argument to `std::invoke` into `f`'s function parameter. The decay-copy happens in the calling thread and wouldn't matter for the thread-local I am looking at anyway. Although I guess "invocation of the copy" is also ambiguous as to whether the call to `std::invoke` itself is meant.

Answer (score 0):

In    `invoke(decay-copy(std::forward<F>(f)), decay-copy(std::forward<Args>(args))...`
Where `f` is callable and your initial function.

Comment: Not quite. As is pointed out in a comment to the question, `f` isn't necessarily a function. It can be any callable object, including an object with an `operator()`; in that case the initial function is the object's `operator()`. And note that `invoke` does not create a thread. The constructor for `std::thread` does that.

Comment: I suggest a rewording:  "Where f is callable and **either is or determines** your initial function". But the answer is very compact and it's not clear if it is a personal position or based on objective arguments.  Could you consider to elaborate a little more ?